# Media queries are not being applied

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

This is my CSS `media query`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .box_url {
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    .box_heading {
        font-size: 13pt;
    }
    .right {
    text-align: left;
    }
    .jane {
    font-size: 10pt;
    }
    .ninja {
    font-size: 12pt;
    }
}
```

and my normal CSS

```css
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.jane {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 70pt;
}
.ninja {
  width: 100%;
    font-size: 25pt;
}
```

But when I run the site some of the media queries aren't being applied.

When I open dev tools in chrome it shows that the media queries are being overridden.

[image: The Screenshot for the dev tools]

I tried using `min-width` too but it still doesn't apply those styles.
 Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: you should revert the order of the declarations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, so you must put your media query after your standard CSS

like this:

```css
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.jane {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 70pt;
}
.ninja {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25pt;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .box_url {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  .box_heading {
    font-size: 13pt;
  }
  .right {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .jane {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .ninja {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
```

Or if you want to keep the media query in first place then you need to more specific in your CSS selectors.

something like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .flex .box_url {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  .flex .box_heading {
    font-size: 13pt;
  }
  .flex .right {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .flex .jane {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .flex .ninja {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.jane {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 70pt;
}
.ninja {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25pt;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The order of importancy on the CSS is as it follows:

1 - Single Declaration

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

2 - Any declaration below the first one

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

body {
    background-color: blue; /* (This will be applied) */
}

/* I'm overwriting my background, so it should be blue now */
```

The position on the header will impact as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

My style.css you overwrite anything on the bootstripe file, in this example, but see the next topic for exceptions

3 - More specific declarations

```
.container button.awesome-button {
    font-size: 14px; /* (This will be applied) */
}

.awesome-button{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Since the first declaration is very specific, that one will be considered. It's like telling 'hey, any `.awesome-button` should be 10px, and then pointing out "Any `button` that's under `.container` and has the class `.awesome-button` should be 14px. So your CSS should respect the most specific and precise coordinates.

4 - CSS as attribute

```
<style>
  .blue{
    color:blue;
  }
</style>

<div class="blue" style="color: red">The color of this div will be red, no matter the class</div>
```

Styling directly on the HTML will get priority over anything on the style sheet.

5 - Elements with `!important` (and then the specific thing if there are more `!important` elements)

```
.awesome-button {
    font-size: 14px !important; /* (This will be applied) */
}

.awesome-button{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Anything with `!important` is, arhm... more important, so you CSS will understand that. However, if there are more `!important` rules, the other rules will be applied within the important elements.

**Be beware:** Using `!important` should be used carefully, and as a last resource in some cases.

---

So, in your case, simple put all your media queries after the "normal" css like this:

```
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.jane {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 70pt;
}
.ninja {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25pt;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .box_url {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  .box_heading {
    font-size: 13pt;
  }
  .right {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .jane {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .ninja {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: both the rule inside the media query and the "normal" rule apply here, so the "normal" rule is being applied due to the cascade.

Your screen size is less than `450px`, so the media query rule applies. The "normal" rule will apply in any condition. The cascade will determine the "winner" by whichever appears later in the stylesheet since they are both equally specific, and that seems to be your "normal" rule.

In your case, you can reverse the order of the rules in your CSS or you can invert the logic, making your mobile case the default view (mobile first!) and using something like a `min-width` media query to change how your text behaves on larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 450px){
    .box_url {
    font-size: 12pt;
    }
    .box_heading {
    font-size: 13pt;
    }
    .right {
    text-align: left;
    }
    .jane {
    font-size: 10pt;
    }
    .ninja {
    font-size: 12pt;
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: never advise to use `!important`, you should read about CSS specificity

Answer (score 0):

make your media query declarations follow the same order as your original css declarations. For example to make my media css work i'd write

HTML

```
<div id="box-A"> 
    <div id="box-B"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box-A #box-B {
    height:  100px; 
}
```

MEDIA CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /*This won't work*/
    #box-B {
        height:  50px;
    }
    /*This will work*/
    #box-A #box-B {
        height:  50px; 
    }
}
```

Hope this fixes your problem.